# как отправить форму которая собержит фото на email

Tags: php, javascript, form

Буду признателен если подскажите как отправить фото на email c `<input type="file">`, у меня приходить только название фото не само изображение, как можно получить изображение?
html:

```
<input type="file" id="fileOne">
```

js:

```
$("#formModel").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "send.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                name: $("#formModel input[name='name']").val(),
                photo: $("#formModel #fileOne").val()
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

php:

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'myemail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Анкета'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Имя: ".$_POST["name"]."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Фото 1: ".$_FILES["photo"]."\n";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отправки фото по email через html форму, необходимо выполнить следующие действия:

1. Загрузить файл на сервер.
2. Прочитать массив `$_FILES` на предмет загруженных файлов
3. Прочитать загруженный файл и закодировать его содержимое в base64
4. Использовать заголовки в mail для добавления файла к письму.

```
Content-Type: image/jpg; name=....
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-disposition: attachment; file=(тут полученная стрка от base64)
```

Comment: Подскажите куда мне нужно вставить это в коде? я с Php только начал разбираться поэтому трудности на каждом шагу

Comment: Вам нужно писать код, а не вставлять кусок моего ответа к себе в программу. Прошу задавать конкретные вопросы, а не фриланс - задачи.

Comment: @ilyaplot если вы вставляете код в ответ, то вы должны быть готовы к тому, что этот код попадет в чужой код.

Comment: @DimaVleskov это заголовки. Они должны быть у вас в $mailHeader.

Comment: @smellyshovel Я показал примеры заголовков, а не код.

Comment: спасибо, уже понятней стало что делать

Comment: @ilyaplot тогда ваше заявление о "фриланс-задачах" становится еще более неуместным.

Answer (score 1):

.val() - содержит только имя файла, а не сам файл. Самый простой способой использовать FormData, но есть проблема с поддержкой старых браузеров.

Детально с примерами но на англ тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax